# Radio button else if

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to programing and am trying to make a simple calculator but using radio buttons for the + - * / buttons. The form has two text boxes for the user with the radio buttons in between and a text box for the answer to go into.    What is wrong with this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int itextBox1 = 0;
        int itextBox2 = 0; 
        int itextBox3 = 0;  

        itextBox1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        itextBox2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

         if (radioButton1.Checked)
         {
              itextBox3 = itextBox1 + itextBox2;
         }
         else if  (radioButton2.Checked)
         {
             itextBox3 = itextBox1 - itextBox2;
         }
         else if (radioButton3.Checked)
         {   
             itextBox3 = itextBox1 * itextBox2;
         }
         else if (radioButton4.Checked)
         { 
             itextBox3 = itextBox1 / itextBox2;
         }
  }//void

 }//class
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with your results once you calculate it.  You are just sticking it in a local variable in the function.

Comment: Why are you using radio buttons rather than normal buttons? A real calculator has normal buttons...

Answer (score 3):

You're calculating a result but not doing anything with it.  Add something like

```
textBox3.Text = itextBox3.ToString();
```

after your calculations.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add this:

```
textBox3.Text = itextBox3.ToString();
```

Did you debug your code? What are the problems.

What is the point of empty event handlers?

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :** You are not displaying the result value on TextBox3.

Try This:

```
itextBox3.Text=itextBox3.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the:

```
textBox3.Text = itextBox3.ToString();
```

Comment: This won't work. itextBox3 is an `int` and it must be converted to `string`.

Answer (score 2):

you can just add

```
MessageBox.Show(itextBox3.ToString());
```

to show your result

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int itextBox1 = 0;
    int itextBox2 = 0; 
    int itextBox3 = 0;  

    itextBox1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    itextBox2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

     if (radioButton1.Checked)
     {
          itextBox3 = itextBox1 + itextBox2;
     }
     else if  (radioButton2.Checked)
     {
         itextBox3 = itextBox1 - itextBox2;
     }
     else if (radioButton3.Checked)
     {   
         itextBox3 = itextBox1 * itextBox2;
     }
     else if (radioButton4.Checked)
     { 
         itextBox3 = itextBox1 / itextBox2;
     }
  MessageBox.Show(itextBox3.ToString());
}
```